# ADT Layout Editor not showing properties

Tags: android, android-layout, adt

I am using ADT 22.0.1 from 5/23/2013.  The properties were working, but they just seemed to stop working.  There is no newer version of ADT available, I have removed and re-added the properties view, and I have reset the perspective.  Nothing seems to be working.

[image: Selecting the items, does not change the properties window at all.]

I also noticed that I am missing the options for device/orientation/api level etc.:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-downloaded the adt bundle and extracted it to a temporary folder.  I then deleted the eclipse directory from my original installation, and copied the newly downloaded eclipse folder into its place.   This resolved my issue.